# Best practice for storing data of many to many models (tags)

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

I would like to represent a Company model in a relational database.
A company is associated with the following tag models:

- Sector
- Core Technology
- Business Model

A company can have multiple values for each tag (i.e. one business model, two sectors, and three core technologies).
A tag-value can appear only once in a specific tag model, however, it can appear in different tag models with the same name (i.e. a core technology with the value SaaS and a business model with the value SaaS)

I came up with two legitimate options to store this relation:

1. Having a table per tag model and a corresponding join table:

   [image]
2. Having a `tags` table with a tag `type` enum field which can be one of the possible values [`sector`, `core_technology`, `business_model`]:

   [image]

The ultimate goal is to be able to get a result set of all companies that have a specific combination of tags.

Initially, I thought that there is no real difference and the second approach might be slightly better, as we have fewer tables and fewer is always better isn't it?!

But then, when I did a quick demo, generated some fake data, and tried to run some queries, I discovered a big difference in the look of the queries that might also affect performance in the case of having many companies in my database.

Here is a query example for the first approach:

```sql
SELECT   c.id,
         c.NAME,
FROM     companies c
JOIN     companies_business_models cbm
ON       (
                  c.id = cbm.company_id)
JOIN     business_models bm
ON       (
                  cbm.business_model_id = bm.id)
JOIN     companies_sectors cs
ON       (
                  c.id = cs.company_id)
JOIN     sectors s
ON       (
                  cs.sector_id = s.id)
JOIN     companies_core_technologies cct
ON       (
                  c.id = cct.company_id)
JOIN     core_technologies ct
ON       (
                  cct.core_technology_id = ct.id)
WHERE    s.NAME IN ('Consumer Staples',
                    'Utilities')
AND      ct.NAME IN ('SaaS',
                     'Computer Vision')
AND      bm.NAME IN ('SaaS')
GROUP BY c.id
HAVING   count(DISTINCT s.NAME) = 2
AND      count(DISTINCT ct.NAME) = 2
AND      count(DISTINCT bm.NAME) = 1
```

This approach seems to be straight forward regarding the WHERE clause but contains many tables and JOINs

Here is a query example for the second approach:

```sql
SELECT c.id,
       c.NAME,
FROM   companies c
       JOIN companies_tags ct
         ON ( c.id = ct.company_id )
       JOIN tags t
         ON ( ct.tag_id = t.id )
WHERE  ( t.type = 'core_technology'
         AND t.NAME IN ( 'SaaS', 'Computer Vision' ) )
        OR ( t.type = 'business_model'
             AND t.NAME IN ( 'SaaS' ) )
        OR ( t.type = 'sector'
             AND t.NAME IN ( 'Consumer Staples', 'Utilities' ) )
GROUP  BY c.id
HAVING Count(DISTINCT t.type, t.NAME) = 5
```

This approach seems to be cleaner on JOINs but less straight forward regarding the WHERE clause.

I would really appreciate to read your thoughts about this issue, and what would be the best practice putting performance first

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer the first model. There are three different attributes. A sector, a core technology, and a business model are three different things. The first model knows that, the second doesn't.

At the moment this doesn't make a difference. They are just tags you assign to a company. But this may change. At some time you may decide that there are sub business models, say "distribution franchise" and "business format franchise" for the business model "franchise" and you even store the contract number with them. Or for sectors you want to know whether they are subject to government subsidies and whether the company gets them. Or for core technologies there is now an ISO code available that you want to store along.

In your first model you would place all these attributes and child or parent tables where they belong. In your second model you'd have nullable attributes that you consider obligatory for some entities and not applicable for the others.

I am not saying that all this is not possible with your second model. It is. But the data model will become murky and subject to explanation. The first model would still be clean and easy to understand by people starting to work with it, because all is clearly laid out.

I am also not saying that I prefer the first model by far. I don't. I prefer it, but I also see the simplicity of the second. And if you are pretty sure that the entities will just stay plain tags, then simple beats expandable.

Comment: I've decided to go with the second approach as I don't expect my tags to have extra fields other than a name, but thanks for presenting the two options and giving the pros and cons of each!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I must complement you for taking the time to design a data model. I often see developers rushing to create new databases, and most of the time that approach backfires.

The two schemata you suggested make sense. I personally would go with the second one for two reasons: First of all, as you mentioned, with this schema the relevant queries require less join operations, which can be very time consuming. Second, it is more scalable. If at some point in the future you will have to add another type of tag, that will be very easy with the second schema, while the first schema will need to be changed and so will the SQL queries and possibly other portions of the application's DAL.